# Internationalization Flutter by intl

Tags: dart, flutter, intl

I've learned flutter. I built an internationalized app using the intl
dependency (follow [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#dart-tools))

1. I run 1st command well (no error message):

> ```
> flutter packages pub run intl_translation:extract_to_arb --output-dir=lib/l10n lib/main.dart
> ```

3 files were generated:

[image]

3. I need to create **intl_{locale}.arb file before run next command**.
4. Next command:

> flutter packages pub run intl_translation:generate_from_arb 
> --output-dir=lib/l10n --no-use-deferred-loading 
> lib/main.dart lib/l10n/intl_*.arb

It always returns a message although the corresponding message (messages_en.dart) file is generated:

```
No @@locale or _locale field found in intl_en, assuming 'en' based on the file name.
No @@locale or _locale field found in intl_messages, assuming 'messages' based on the file name.
```

**How can I run the 2nd command without the messages, because I think they are unexpected messages ?**

Comment: have you mentioned supportedLocales? supportedLocales: [
    const Locale('en', 'US'), // English
    const Locale('he', 'IL'), // Hebrew
    // ... other locales the app supports
  ],

Comment: yep, I mentioned them in main.dart. maybe they are message not error

Comment: you need to obtain a set of files similare to these (en + es in this case):
intl_es.arb
intl_en.arb
intl_messages.arb
messages_all.dart
messages_es.dart
messages_en.dart
messages_messages.dart

Comment: yep, already. I have the files, but I always see the message No @@locale or _locale field found in intl_messages, assuming 'messages' based on the file name. this is my question now.

Answer (score 18):

You should write in each file the following. Then flutter will automatically identify the language.

```
{
  "@@locale": "en",
  "title": "Flutter Example App",
  "@title": {
    "type": "text",
    "placeholders": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1.

```
flutter packages pub run intl_translation:generate_from_arb \ --output-dir=lib/l10n --no-use-deferred-loading \ lib/main.dart lib/l10n/intl_*.arb
```

should be changed to:

```
flutter pub pub run intl_translation:extract_to_arb --output-dir=lib/l10n ****lib/DemoLocalizations.dart****
```

(where ****lib/DemoLocalizations.dart**** should be update to the file where you created this file from the steps you created.

2.

you will have the strings generated. these need to copied to intl*.arb

3.

then you should run:

```
flutter pub pub run intl_translation:generate_from_arb --output-dir=lib/l10n    --no-use-deferred-loading ****lib/DemoLocalizations.dart**** lib/l10n/intl_*.arb
```

Comment: it does not work.
1st: I updated:
flutter pub pub run intl_translation:extract_to_arb --output-dir=lib/l10n lib/main_internationalization.dart
--- there is only a file generated (intl_messages.arb)
2nd command did not run:
flutter pub pub run intl_translation:generate_from_arb --output-dir=lib/l10n --no-use-deferred-loading lib/main_internationalization.dart lib/l10n/intl_*.arb
return error:
https://pastebin.com/90snxBhc

Comment: bro, I think that it's simply response message bcz I downloaded + ran the commands with the source code from the guideline (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#dart-tools). It returned the same messages.

Answer (score 0):

Between the steps you mentioned 1. and 2. you should copy the new strings to intl*.arb.

Comment: There is only a file intl_messages.arb file which generated after I run 1st command. the file's content is the same with guideline source code already. what do you mean ?

Comment: hmm, creating intl_{locale}.arb file is missing. I updated my question already. How can I run 2nd without error like: No @@locale or _locale field found in intl_en, assuming 'en' based on the file name. Thanks!!!